# I need to write to a SQL Express db in my ASP.NET web site, is NETWORK SERVICE the account to use?

Tags: asp.net

I need to write to a SQL Express db in my ASP.NET web site, is NETWORK SERVICE the account to use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Local Service is what I think the recommended account is for security reasons.  It limits the service's access to the machine so that if the service is hacked, then a minimal amount of damage can be done to the machine.

However, I have had issues where certain operations couldn't be completed because of the limited rights of the Local Service account, and I've had to use the Local System account instead, which is significantly less safe from a security standpoint.

Also see this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143170%28SQL.90%29.aspx